# Maintain path redirect after signup in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

A user needs to be have an account in order to use the service. After the user clicks on the link that was sent to them and if they do not have an account, they are prompted to register for one. However, after they signup, they need to be redirected back to the original link that they clicked on. I am not sure how to go about doing this because I am unfamiliar with class based views in Django. I have the following Class for the Signup Form in views.py:

```
class SignUpView(bracesviews.AnonymousRequiredMixin,
             bracesviews.FormValidMessageMixin,
             generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.SignupForm
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_valid_message = "You're signed up!"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        r = super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)
        username = form.cleaned_data["email"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
        user = auth.authenticate(email=username, password=password)
        auth.login(self.request, user)
        return r
```

Then, in forms.py I have the following:

```
class SignupForm(authtoolsforms.UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields["email"].widget.input_type = "email"  # ugly hack
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('type', placeholder='recruiter'),
            Field('email', placeholder="Enter Email", autofocus=""),
            Field('name', placeholder="Enter Full Name"),
            Field('password1', placeholder="Enter Password"),
            Field('password2', placeholder="Re-enter Password"),
            Submit('sign_up', 'Sign up', css_class="btn-warning"),
            )
```

I was thinking about using self.request.path in a function to get the path after "?next=" in the url as I was able to successfully do with a login redirect to the original link, but I am unsure about how to preserve the url with signing up.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the built-in context processors by including the request path at the end of your signup page URL.

If you have a link to the Signup page that the user is clicking on, you can include the request path like so:

```
<a href="{% url 'user-signup' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Signup</a>
```

If you're redirecting the user from a view, append the next parameter with the request object from the view, something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

class ClassViewThatRedirectsUser(View):
  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("%s%s%s" % (reverse('user-signup'), "?next=", self.request.path))
```

Make sure you have the context processors included in your settings file, for Django 1.10 it's included under OPTIONS in TEMPLATES, it will look something like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
```